# List sorting which contains string starting with underscore

Tags: c#, list, sorting, criteria, collation

So here is what I got:
I have a list with these strings in it: "student", "Students", "students", "Student" and "_Students".

What I have done:

```
List<string> sort = new List<string>() { "student", "Students", "students", "Student","_Students" };
List<string> custsort = sort.OrderBy(st => st[0]).ThenBy(s => s.Length)
                                                             .ToList();
```

But this gives me this sort:

```
Student
Students
_Students
student
students
```

And what I want is:

```
_Students
Student
Students
student
students
```

I can't figure it out how to sort them because that damn underscore is located between the upperCase and lowerCase letters in the ASCII table.

Comment: Is '_' your only special character? What other requirements do you have?

Comment: Also, do you want to sort case sensitively? I guess so, but it's not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex to determine whether the first character is a letter and apply a weight to it.

```
int GetWeight(char c)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(c.ToString(), @"[a-zA-Z]") ? c : 0;
}

List<string> sort = new List<string>() { "student", "Students", "students", "Student","_Students" };
List<string> custsort =
    sort.OrderBy(st => GetWeight(st[0]))
        .ThenBy(s => s.Length)
        .ToList();
```

This way if you need any other special rules you can modify the `GetWeight` function and your Linq will be unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

You could, for example, consider the `_` to be a `(space)`, like this:

```
List<string> custsort = sort.OrderBy(st => st.Replace('_', ' '))
                            .ToList();
```

This will put the `_Students` before all the other `*students`... At this point sorting by `ThenBy(s => s.Length)` would be useless.

This clearly WILL create a little disorder if you already have strings that start with a space. If you have them, change the space with another character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ordering criteria that just returns true or false - any items that are false get put before any true ones. In the code below I've added a first `OrderBy` that puts items starting with an underscore first.

```
List<string> custsort = sort.OrderBy(st => st[0] != '_')
                        .ThenBy(st => st[0])
                        .ThenBy(s => s.Length)
                        .ToList();
```

The rest of the query uses the same rules you had before - order by the first character, then by the length of each string.